# Create a stored procedure that dynamically union tables having extension .csv

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2019, dynamic-sql

I have a database named **Fire** that has 41 tables with the name format **dbo.[#######.csv]**.

All the tables have the different number of column name like **table 1 column** A,B and **table 2 column** A,B,C and **table 3 column** A,B,C,D etc. First select the table that have highest number of column in a table and by using alter condition add column missing column in all the tables. All Columns have same datatypes varchar(max). I want to create a stored procedure to UNION all the table and stored result in a new table.

I've created a simple stored procedure with the tables name's hard coded but I'm having difficulty how to approach the issue of having the stored procedure created dynamically. I'm using SQL Server 2019.All 41 tables are coming form azure data factory.

Comment: If you're creating a new table by merging the original 41, then you should use that merged table instead and discard the original 41!  Therefore, you only need to do this operation once and so trying to build a dynamic stored procedure to do it is overkill.

Comment: All table have no primary key. so i cannot merge them .

Comment: Phil is not saying use the `MERGE` operator, rather he means why can't you just hard code the columns of all of the tables once and insert the results into a new table, then drop the old tables...Why would you need a dynamic stored procedure for this after the first time you create the new table?

Comment: i want to take union of all the that why is can hard code the columns.

Comment: Basically my scenario is to take union of tables dynamically that end with csv .And there are 41 table that end with csv. And my tables have no primary keys, foreign key  and number of columns are not same . I first add columns in the table and  in the end i will take union.

Comment: If you cannot meaningfully merge the tables into one /permanently/, then what are you hoping to achieve by "merging" them into one /temporarily/, using stored procedure, however "dynamic" you manage to make it??  
Do the columns named A, B, C, etc., even /mean/ the same thing in every table?  If not, then you're potentially 'union'ing Apples, Oranges, Duck-billed Platypuses and Carburettors.

Comment: After taking union of all the table i want to store it into a new table that i will use this table for further work. That's why i will take union of all tables.